# How to iterate through each xml file in root of a jar

Tags: java

during runtime of my app I need to iterate through each xml file which lies in the root of my jar.

I know that I can access a concrete file like this

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "filename.xml" );
```

But how can I receive the list of files which are in the root of the jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html).

**Java: Listing the contents of a resource directory**
*The ClassLoader.getResource() function can be a really handy way to load up your files in Java. The files can be loaded from any folder or JAR file on your classpath. However, the API disappointingly lacks a way to list all the files in the directory. (No, getResources() does not do it.) This utility function comes to the rescue!*

Comment: The link you provided explains in detail. Please add relevant contents from site to the answer.

Comment: its one function all relevant @Jayan !

Comment: any idea how to pack this method into a test case? So that it can be tested?